# how to make drop down list item selected in database

Tags: php, sql, select, menu, mysqli

I have a mysql table with about 40 items in it. What I want to do is reference those 40 items in a form on my webpage with a drop down list. 
Instead of writing it out all 40 items like the following to know if an item has been selected:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<option value="Health & Beauty"<?php if (isset($_POST['SiteType']) && ($_POST['SiteType'] == 'Health & Beauty')) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Health & Beauty</option></select>
</body>
</html>
and so on 40 times...
```

I am wondering how I could do it instead by using an SQL statement like the following:
here is what I have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sitetypes";
$f = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or trigger_error("Query: $sql\n<br />Mysqli Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($f, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value="' . $row2['SiteTypeID'] . '">' . $row2['SiteType'] . '</option><\select>';
}
```

The code above produces a nice drop down list, but I don't know how to make the database know when an item is selected by a user. What code do I write to make that happen? Can I use the SQL statement option or do I have to write each item out like I wrote at the beginning of this post.

Comment: What do you mean by _how to make the database know when an item is selected by a user_ , you select a value and submit it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

Add **Select** Attribute to your Table of type varchar

```
alter table user add Selected varchar(255)
```

Give them all values to '0'

and in html page

```
<select name="sitename">
    <option></option>
    <!-- your options -->
</select>
```

and when form is submitted by your you simply use this

```
echo $_POST['sitename'];
```

Then use this query to database know user selected this field in **usertable** or where you want

```
Update user set selcted='$_POST["sitename"]' where userid='currectuserid'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by adding Select Attribute to my Table and Enum ('0','1') Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Updated my answer this is what you want if i understand right.

Comment: Manwal, I think you are confusing the OP more than he is now. Why is `alter` and `update` statements here? @user3286022 Do you need the selected option to be set as default on page load when the user selects an option?

Comment: Hi Manwal, my table already has a column sitetypes with all the items already listed in it, I don't want to set those items to zero. I am having trouble understanding your post. In my new column I create in my table do I have to create 40 or so items all with value of 0.

Comment: To I can has cheezburger, if there is an option to do that, that would be great. how do i code that.

Comment: @user3286022 Yes you can do that, one more question, how are you submitting this value? I don't see any submit button your code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sitetypes";
$f = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or trigger_error("Query: $sql\n<br />Mysqli Error: " .mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($f, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value="' . $row2['SiteTypeID'] . ' '.($row2['SiteTypeName'] == $_POST['SiteType'] ? 'selected="selected"':'').'">' . $row2['SiteType'] . '</option><\select>';
}
```

I'm not sure if the syntax is right, but you get the idea. 
Edit: as I Can Haz Cheeseburger suggested u need to get the name from the db (not id) or pass the ID through POST

Comment: The `SiteTypeID` wouldn't be `==` to `SiteType`